# Remove comments from json file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with comments shown below, I can't read the file in python as it is an invalid JSON file and I would like to have a pythonic way to remove all the lines in the file starting with /* as shown below:

```
/* 1 */
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abe"),
    "id" : "149",
    "objectType" : "act"
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abe415"),
    "id" : "449899009",
    "objectType" : "ity"
}]
```

I have tried the code below but getting the error in loads() of JSON:
'''

```
import JSON

with open('data.json', 'r+',encoding='utf-8-sig') as handle:
    fixed_json = ''.join(line for line in handle if not line.startswith('/*'))
    final_data = json.loads(fixed_json)

print(final_data)
```

'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 13 (char 16)'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code looks correct, but that's not valid JSON even with the comments removed. `ObjectId("abe")` is improperly quoted.

Comment: ...and since it contains comments it's pretty clear it was never intended to be valid JSON. Can you tell us what generates this output?

Comment: If the comments are as shown in the question then it would be trivial to preprocess the file to remove them. Then you'll have to figure out how to handle ObjectId because that's not valid JSON

Comment: @jordanm I think I can remove "_id" as it is generated by MongoDB or studio 3T, and doesn't hold any information for my analysis.

Comment: I think I can strip the "_id" as well as it doesn't hold any information for my analysis.

Comment: this is an x/y problem. the solution is not to remove the comment and somehow fix the json, it's to generate actual json in the first place

Answer (score 0):

#### For your special input that you didn't share here, this is my solution with `regex`:

> Note: you need to check your input errors and convert `false`, `null`, or other keywords to strings like `"false"`.

```
import json
import re
import emoji
    

with open('tweets.json', 'r+') as handle:
   
    fixed_json = ''.join(line for line in handle)  
    # remove emojis
    fixed_json = emoji_pattern.sub(r'', fixed_json)
    fixed_json = emoji.replace_emoji(fixed_json, replace='')
    fixed_json = fixed_json.replace(' ', '')
    fixed_json = fixed_json.replace('false', '\"false\"')
    fixed_json = fixed_json.replace('null', '\"null\"')

rx = re.compile(r"\/\*.*\/([\n\s]*\{[\w\W]*?\}[\n\s]*)(?=\/\*.*\/)")

parts = rx.split(fixed_json) 

print(parts[0])
print(len(parts))


tweets=[]
parts = parts[1:]
for tweet in parts:
    
    tweet = tweet.replace('\udbb8\udf35\udbb8\udf38', '')
    tweet = emoji.replace_emoji(tweet, replace='')
    
    tweet = json.dumps(tweet)
    
    tweets.append(json.loads(tweet) )
print(len(tweets))

# Remove empty elements
result = []
for tweet in tweets:
    if len(tweet.strip())>0:
        result.append(tweet)
print(len(result))

# convert string to json
results = []
for res in result:
    try:
        results.append(eval(res))
    except:
        continue
print(len(results))
```

Output:

```
/*10000Tweets*/



19999
19998
10000
5022 #tweets that converted to JSON successfully
```

Comment: I am getting the following error

' File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7876/2647836232.py", line 6, in <module>
    fixed_json = str(eval(fixed_json))

  File "<string>", line 116
    {
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax '

Comment: @Mr_yassh what is your python version?

Comment: its 
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @Mr_yassh Updated! check it again.

Comment: @Mr_yassh or upgrade your python to Python 3.10.4

Comment: still the same error @Shahab, but I have just noticed that I don't have "," between two documents and I have also edited the question and the given JSON file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247949/discussion-between-mr-yassh-and-shahab-rahnama).